# Ubuntu 16.04 .htaccess issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed LAMP successfully. I have created my projects under `var/www/html`. I am using `.htaccess` for a project. But it is not working. I tried to link the page `<a href="next">Next</a>`. But it is showing url not found.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pg=$1
```

Changed config in `apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And in `sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

Please help to work out this.I have been trying more than a day.

Comment: We need additional information: 1. the exact URL you request that should be rewritten, 2. where that `.htaccess` file is located and its file system permissions, 3. the entries in your http servers error log file when you restart the http server.

Comment: Did you enable `mod_rewrite` for your apache?

Comment: Yeah.I enabled by using the command sudo a2enmod rewrite

Comment: Just i nedd to hide the .php extension.And the htaccess file is located in my project root folder

Comment: That rule you posted will _not_ only remove the `.php` extension. It rewrites a URL like `https://example.com/5` internally to `/index.php?pg=5` (in an insecure way).

Comment: Hai Bro.Thanks.It is working now.I have done a big mistake in htaccess file.Thanks a lot.